# ClassCastException with OpenJPA in Jboss 6.0

Tags: java, classloader, jboss6.x, openjpa

Jboss 6 comes with JPA 2.0 (`hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar`) and Hibernate 3.6.6 as the implementation.

I have a web application that has OpenJPA 2.0 library (openjpa-all-2.1.0.jar). I have set the classloader isolation in the jboss-web.xml as shown below

```
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
    <loader-repository>
        some.example:loader=some-webapp.war
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

When I deploy the application I get this error

> ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=some.war#some state=Create: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

This is strange since, `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl` already implements `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

I did a `-version:class` to check where the `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` is being loaded from and it appears that it's being loaded from the web application first and then from `jboss6\common\lib`

> [Loaded javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$1 from vfs:/home/sathwik/apps/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/some-webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/openjpa-all-2.1.0.jar/]
>
> [Loaded javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider from vfs:/home/sathwik/apps/jboss-6.1.0.Final/common/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar/]

From the `Manifest.mf` file i was able to gather the JDK version used to compile
`hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar` is compiled with `Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_19`,
`openjpa-all-2.1.0` is compiled with `Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_22`

Can anyone help me out in understanding why this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OpenJPA Dependencies page](http://openjpa.apache.org/build-and-runtime-dependencies.html), the `openjpa-all` JAR file

> [...] includes the OpenJPA core code plus all of the runtime dependencies for Java SE environments

You're not running in a JavaSE envrionment, you're in a full-blown JavaEE environment, which already has many of the ancillary API classes contained within the `openjpa-all` JAR. As a result, you're getting conflicts caused by loading classes of the same name, but from different classloaders.

You should replace `openjpa-all` with more specific JAR files (i.e. `openjpa-2.1.0.jar` and whatever others are necessary to make it work - see the above page).

Comment: skaffman, thanks for your quick reply. I was able to deploy the application after deploying openjpa-2.1.0.jar instead of openjpa-all.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening with the classloader here. Why is it complaining a ClassCastException.

Comment: @Sathwick: Java treats classes loaded from different classloaders as different, even if they have the same name and the same bytecode. If you try to cast an object between these classes, you get the exception. Which classloader is used for any given class can be hard to predict, especially in complex environments  like JBoss.